# find out new image width height after browser window resize

Tags: html, image

i have an image and i have placed markers on it.
problem is that when the browser window resizes, the image size also changes and thus the marker comes to a different position than where it was before.
so, i want to find out the new positions and dimensions of the image after the browser window size changes.
I want to find out the new dimensions of the image, but nothing has worked till now.

i have used clientWidth , offsetWidth, naturalWidth and it all shows the same width before and after the window resize.

(I actually have a zoom property too and it shows the same width even after using zoom), so I am not sure what's wrong?

how do I find out the new image height width and positions after it is zoomed or after the browser window size is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger an event on window resize and find the image height

```
window.addEventListner("resize",function(){
     var img = document.getElementById("img1");
     console.log(img.clientWidth);
}
```

Comment: i am using reactjs and this doesnt seem to be working